# Is there a way of switching/changing the "ON" condition in a SQL query when the columns do not match?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables (t1 and t2).  I want to print/keep all records from t1 (we'll treat t1 as the left table). I want to perform a JOIN with t1 and t2 on two columns, but there's a problem.  Table t1 consists of columns c1 and c2.  Table t2 consists of columns c3, c4, and c5.  I want to perform a JOIN between t1 and t2 on c1 (from t1) and c3 (from t2), but I **also** want to do a JOIN between t1 and t2 on c2 (from t1) and c4 (from t2) **if records from c1 and c3 do not match**.

[Here are the two tables.  Completely fictitious, but applicable
to my real, work-related problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSDdb.png)

[The table below is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlTsc.png)
All the records/rows from t1 are printed.

I greatly appreciate anyone who comes forward with query solutions.  With that being said, is there a way to solve this problem without UNION? Also, I am using SQL Server.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Why would you say without union? Seems you might be making an assumption about the performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the input and output data, I think you mean to compare c2 and c4 if *c1 and c3* differ, not *c1 and c2*. I recreated the tables in sql and this code below gives the result you're looking for.

In that case you can just join and use an `OR`:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON
    t1.c1 = t2.c3
    OR t1.c2 = t2.c4;
```

Comment: I replicated this query (for my real dataset of ~27,000 rows) and it runs really slowly.  In reality, t1 is ~27,000 rows and t2 is 1,000,000+ rows.  (Of course, I can't just upload commerical data/info to this site)

Comment: @BasirMiah Performance issues would require a different question.

Comment: Maybe a `FULL JOIN` would be more suitable, but I think the `LEFT JOIN` is enough for the example the OP included.